# アソシエーションした後のメッセージを作成し、保存する方法（コードの書き方）を教えて欲しいです。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

メッセージアプリを作成中です。
１対１でメッセージをやり取りしようとしています。

やりたいことは、ユーザー一覧画面でユーザーを選択して、選択したユーザーの詳細画面でメッセージ投稿して、そのユーザー詳細画面でメッセージを表示したいです。
ユーザー詳細画面で送信ユーザーと受信ユーザーがどちらもメッセージを見れるようにしたいです。
（よくあるチャットアプリのようなイメージです）

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
      
end
```

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user = User.find(1)
    @sent_messages = @user.sent_messages.order(created_at: :desc)
  end
  
  def new
  end
  
  def create
params[current_user.id], recipient_id: params[:recipient_id])
    @message = Message.new(message: params[:message], sender_id: params[current_user.id], recipient_id: params[:id])

      if @message.save
        flash[:notice] = "メッセージ作成に成功しました"
        redirect_to "/users/#{:id}"
      else
        flash[:error] = @message.errors.full_messages
        render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
  end
end
```

上記のコントローラーのcreateアクション後フラッシュメッセージで以下のように表示されます。
["Sender must exist", "Recipient must exist"]

ログを見ると
@message
nil
と表示されるので、パラメーターが届いてないようです。

@messageのパラメーターを作成方法（コードの書き方？）が間違っていると思いますが、どこが間違っているか教えてもらえますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

エラーメッセージから推測するに、

```
@message = Message.new(message: params[:message], sender_id: params[current_user.id], recipient_id: params[:id])
```

の部分で Message モデルと関連付けられている sender および recipient が存在せず、モデルのバリデーションか何かに引っかかって `Message.new` が失敗して返り値が `nil` になっていると思われます。

Sender については、おそらく `params[current_user.id]` としているのが誤りです。`current_user` を設定した上で `current_user.id` のみになるはずです。Recipient については、view からちゃんと params を渡せているかどうか確認してください。